# Register for Courses Java

Tags: java, methods

I have been working on a code that registers students for courses. I was given a teachers copy and needed to write the code for the validateChoice method. I have it completed but I am still getting two errors. The program is recognizing 0 as a duplicate instead of an invalid course number, and is allowing the user to duplicate twice before throwing an invalid message. There should be no duplicates allowed. Any ideas on why this would happen? I have already turned this in because it runs correctly with the course codes I was given for the assignment, I just want to know for personal reference. Thanks!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package u6a1_consoleregisterforcourse;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
 * @author omora
 */
public class U6A1_ConsoleRegisterForCourse {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    
     
    System.out.println("Kim's Copy");
            
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //choice is the current menu selection
    //firstChoice is the first menu selection mande by the user
    //secondChoice is the second menu selection mande by the user
    //thirdChoice is the third menu selection mande by the user
    // a choice of 0 means the choice has not been made yet
    int choice;
    int firstChoice = 0, secondChoice = 0, thirdChoice = 0;
    int totalCredit = 0;
    String yesOrNo = "";
    

    
    do {

        choice = getChoice(input);
        
        switch (ValidateChoice(choice, firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice, totalCredit)) {
            case -1:
                System.out.println("**Invalid** - Your selection of " + choice + " is not a recognized course.");
                break;
            case -2:
                System.out.println("**Invalid** - You have already registerd for this " +  ChoiceToCourse(choice) + " course.");
                break;
            case -3:
                System.out.println("**Invalid** - You can not register for more than 9 credit hours.");
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Registration Confirmed for course " + ChoiceToCourse(choice) );
                totalCredit += 3;
                if (firstChoice == 0)
                    firstChoice = choice;
                else if (secondChoice == 0)
                    secondChoice = choice;
                else if (thirdChoice == 0)
                    thirdChoice = choice;
                break;
        }

        WriteCurrentRegistration(firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice);
        
        System.out.print("\nDo you want to try again? (Y|N)? : ");
        
        yesOrNo = input.next().toUpperCase();
        
    } while (yesOrNo.equals("Y"));

    System.out.println("Thank you for registering with us");
    
}


public static int getChoice(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Please type the number inside the [] to register for a course");
    System.out.println("[1]IT4782\n[2]IT4784\n[3]IT4786\n[4]IT4789\n[5]IT2230\n[6]IT3345\n[7]IT3349");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
    return (input.nextInt());

}

//This method validates the user menu selection
//against the given registration business rules
//it returns the following code based on the validation result
// -1 = invalid, unrecognized menu selection
// -2 = invalid, alredy registered for the course
// -3 = invalid, No more than 9 credit hours allowed
// 0 = menu selection is valid
   public static int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit) {

    // TO DO - Add Code to:
    // Validate user menu selection (the int choice method argument)
    // against the given registration business rules
    int result = 0;  
        
    
    if (choice <=0 ||choice >7){  
    result = -1; 
    }
 
    if(choice==firstChoice||choice == secondChoice||choice == thirdChoice) {
    result = -2;  
   }
   if(totalCredit == 3) {            
    result = 0;
   }    
   
   if (totalCredit > 9) {        
     result = -3;  
      } 
           
    return result;
}

public static void WriteCurrentRegistration(int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice) {

    if (firstChoice == 0)
        System.out.println("Current course registration:  { none } " );     
    else if (secondChoice == 0)
        System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + " }" );
    else if (thirdChoice == 0)
        System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + 
                ", " + ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice) + " }");
    else
        System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + 
                ", " + ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice) + ", " + ChoiceToCourse(thirdChoice) + " }");
    
}

public static String ChoiceToCourse(int choice) {
        String course = "";
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                course = "IT4782";
                break;
            case 2:
                course = "IT4784";
                break;
            case 3:
                course = "IT4786";
                break;
            case 4:
                course = "IT4789";
                break;
            case 5:
                course = "IT2230";
                break;
            case 6:
                course = "IT3345";
                break;
            case 7:
                course = "IT3349";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return course;
}


}
```

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess - it doesn't look like you're storing state anywhere...that is to say, your application doesn't actually keep track of anything it's written before.  I'd need to actually run the application to see why it's doing this, but I would also recommend that you look into an IDE like IntelliJ to debug and trace what's going on in your application, too.

Comment: You should follow the **Java Naming Conventions**: variable and method names always start with lowercase.